# c# how to add a link to response message

Tags: c#, user-controls, response

I have a html response message that I want to add a link to. Is it possible to add a link to following:

```
responseMsg.InnerText = "Your postcode is in the network, so please proceed to Step 2.";
```

I tried the following but it caused the user control to crash:

```
responseMsg.InnerText = "Your postcode is in the network, so please <a href="#">proceed to Step 2</a>.";
```

Comment: replace the double quotes around the # with single quotes and put an @ sign in front. i.e @"Your post...<a href='#'>...

Comment: The problem is obvious, thanks to the syntax highlighter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `InnerHtml` instead:

```
responseMsg.InnerHtml = "Your postcode is in the network, so please <a href='#'>proceed to Step 2</a>.";
```

Use can either escape the double quotes in the anchor tag like `<a href=\"#\">...</a>`

or you can use single quotes like `<a href='#'>...</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way

Escape the quotes

```
responseMsg.InnerText = "Your postcode is in the network, so please <a href=\"#\">proceed to Step 2</a>.";
```

OR use single quote on the href

```
responseMsg.InnerText = "Your postcode is in the network, so please <a href='#'>proceed to Step 2</a>.";
```

Comment: Both options result in the <a> tag to display as text, not as a link.

Comment: what control is responseMsg? does it have InnerHTML property?

Answer (score 0):

change the double quotes for the single quotes

```
responseMsg.InnerText = "Your postcode is in the network, so please "<a href='http://proceedtosteptwo.aspx' title='this is a test'>proceed to Step 2</a>";
```

I hope this work for you.